# How do I prevent circular references

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am having problems with circular references. Suppose I have the following hierarchy: `ViewControllerA` and two objects `ObjB` and `ObjC` (these two objects are `UIVIew` based objects visible on `ViewControllerA`). Suppose I have created a category `UIView+SuperExtensions` and this category is used by all 3 objects and all these objects have class files. Do I have to do a `#import "UIView+SuperExtensions.h"` on the classes of all 3 objects or just on the `ViewControllerA`.

I am importing on all 3 objects right now and am experiencing a lot of circular reference problems. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Importing alone won't create circular references. You'll have to give some more concrete examples (code maybe).

Comment: He isn't talking about retain cycles, but import cycles.

Comment: You should be able to import category definitions in all 3 of your .m files.  I can't think why you'd need them in the .h files and that would mean no circularity problems.  If that approach gives errors, you may have to give actual examples.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad he says "circulars references". That to me is more "retain cycles" than "import cycles". Maybe I just interpreted it incorrectly though.

Comment: In general, you can break circular reference cycles by substituting references to specific classes with references to interfaces (ie: a protocol).  Even in simple C code: Headers can include just forward declarations, which can be separate from headers that actually define structures (and may use pointers to forward declared but undefined structures and classes).  

Designing with some amount of "dependency injection" goes a long way to making this just work naturally.  (ie: instantiate an API passing in malloc/free fn pointers rather than including the header that defines malloc/free in impl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* import a header everywhere, where you use it. Especially you should not rely that an imported header imports another header.

Addition for Hot Licks:

```
// Inside a .m
#import "Subclass.h"
#import "BaseClass.h"
// You should import BaseClass.h, if you use its contents, even you can be pretty sure that Subclass.h already imported it
```

If this leads to circular references, you have another problem. In most cases it is, that one imported the header of in another header instead of using a forward declaration witch `@class`.

Comment: You contradict yourself.  You can use an `@class` *instead of* importing the class's header file, where you only need to create a reference to the class, and not reference any methods or fields/properties.  This is usually sufficient to prevent import cycles.

Comment: This is, what I wrote.

Comment: Probably you misunderstood my first sentence. I did *not* write: "You should import a header wherever, where you use any of its content in any way." I wrote: "You should import a header everywhere, where you use it [=the header]".

Comment: How do you "use" a header, other than by importing it?

Comment: You use it by importing it. I did not say anything else. I would give you the advice to reread the Q and my answer. You will see your misunderstanding. The OP perfectly understood it.

Comment: @HotLicks I added an addition especially for you. Maybe you are understanding now, that paragraph 1 and 2 cannot contradict, because they have completely different subjects.